# Annotations for enable/disable GUI elements

Tags: java, annotations

I have barely used annotations in Java and I am not used to this. I would like to ask you if the below part of code can be written with annotations? If yes then how?

```
if (e.getSource() == checkBox) {
   if (checkBox.getSelectedIndex() > 1) {
      rdbtn1.setEnabled(false);
      rdbtn2.setEnabled(false);
      rdbtn3.setEnabled(false);
   } else {
      rdbtn1.setEnabled(true);
      rdbtn2.setEnabled(true);
      rdbtn3h.setEnabled(true);
   }
}
```

It's a piece of code that I often use with GUI elements and I want to find a better way to do that.

Comment: With plain annotations? No. You would need a framework which would process and use these annotations to inject the necessary code. Although you could of course write an own annotation processor or something similar. But I guess what this would be an overkill in your case. What exactly is it you want to add automatically? The check for the source? Or the whole code?

Comment: I am trying to find a better way to enable/disable the radiobuttons. In this example radiobuttons depend on the selected item of a checkbox. Another scenario could be when you interact with an other GUI element. For example when the user press a button I wanna prevent him to press on the radiobuttons by disabling them. I am not sure if it can be done with annotations. That's why I asked! ;)

Comment: Hm, I am still not sure that annotations are what you are looking for. Maybe you would rather need a better approach. Depending on where the code is: You could try something like `rdbtn1.setEnabled(selectedIndex > 1)` - in one method which is called whenever the selection changes. You could also extend the radio buttons and implement them as property change listener, making sure that they are informed whenever the selection changes. But what you would really need is the possibility to bind the properties together. However, I don't know whether this can be achieved in Swing..

Comment: well as I said I am not sure about the annotations... but your second approach looks interesting. I should give a try